# Software Center is stuck for Dropbox "applying changes"

Tags: software-center, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dropbox install stuck at 99%, how do I fix it? (and any dpkg errors)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154671/dropbox-install-stuck-at-99-how-do-i-fix-it-and-any-dpkg-errors)

I wanted to download and install Dropbox, but it has been stuck "applying changes" for almost an hour. I'm new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure how to cancel or restart it…
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try updating using the command line. Use the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

If you encounter any error, please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Just wait a little, especially if you installed a heavy program / a lot of packages in addition to Dropbox.
If you already waited for a few minutes, try relaunching the Software Center.

Comment: Been almost an hour. I closed it and reopened, but it's at the same spot. Anything else I can try?