# Ubuntu software center stuck in applying/canceling/searcing

Tags: software-center

I can't install anything from software center because it is stuck at applying/searching, when i cancel it, it is stuck at canceling. Then software center gives me a pop up box that it needs to be repaired, so i click "repair" but in the progress of "repairing installed software" it is stuck at applying changes. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Try to see answers from this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/146798/ubuntu-software-center-does-not-proceed-from-applying-changes

Answer (score 12):

I would try doing `sudo killall software-center`. That should terminate software center. You may need to do `sudo killall dpkg` if there's still the 'installation' stuffs in the background.

**Or:**

1. Try adding the -9 argument to them, so it's `sudo killall -9 software-center` and `sudo killall -9 dpkg`
2. Then`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
3. Finally `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Before killing anything, close all windows and make sure there is not a EULA popped up behind the Software Centre. These EULAs are very common, especially with software outside of the main repositories.

if that fails, try

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

or

```
dpkg --configure -a
```