# I accidentally canceled 16.04 Upgrade halfway through; dpkg status locked

Tags: apt, upgrade, bash, dpkg

I was upgrading from `15.10` to `16.04` and I got some prompts about config files having changed, e.g. `/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop`. So I type `D` to see the diff, but then accidentally hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (intending to copy out the diff) instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Just a slip of the fingers.

Anyway, this promptly seemed to quit the upgrade process (although leaving the terminal in a weird state), but of course it wasn't finished installing! Although running `sudo do-release-upgrade` gives
**No new release found**. How do I get back into the installation process? I can tell dpkg is running because it's locked. `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` yields:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
dpkg    29329 root    3uW  REG    8,7        0 262367 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

I'm worried now that if I restart my computer, it won't boot up at that point, and I'm hoping there's a way to resume installation without having to reboot into recovery mode etc. Kind of annoyed too that it quit so easily by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

One option of course, [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146798/ubuntu-software-center-does-not-proceed-from-applying-changes), is to kill my `dpkg` process  then try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`... but I figured I'd ask here if there are any ideas before I do something that could be irreversible.

Alternatively, if someone knows that the specific stage I stopped at (config files) is early enough that it's nbd, that would also be helpful!

Comment: I was tempted to ask "is there a way to get back into an old process in general?" but that seems impossible since the process was killed with `SIGINT`.

Comment: Okay, I got impatient and did the kill and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it seems to have gotten me right back to where it was before! Woo :)

Comment: (Still not certain, but it seems very promising)

Comment: ...Okay, it finished. I'm going to restart now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked! I'm now the happy user of 16.04.

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo kill -TERM <PID>
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Please feel free to "accept" your answer by clicking the gray check-mark beside it; that way other people can see at a glance that your issue is resolved. I'm glad you got it working!

Comment: yep, will do, just waiting out the 2 days :)

Comment: Dude, this worked for me in 2022 (upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 hung), you got yourself another 10 Brownie points!